# two php arrays - sort one array with the value order of another

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have two PHP arrays like so:

1. Array of X records containing the ID
   of Wordpress posts (in a particular
   order)
2. Array of Wordpress posts

The two arrays look something like this:

**Array One (Sorted Custom Array of Wordpress Post IDs)**

```
Array (  
  [0] => 54
  [1] => 10
  [2] => 4
)
```

**Array Two (Wordpress Post Array)**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [post_author] => 1
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 54
            [post_author] => 1
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 10
            [post_author] => 1
    )
)
```

I would like to sort the array of wordpress posts with the order of the ID's in the first array.

I hope this makes sense, and thanks in advance of any help.

Tom

edit: The server is running PHP Version 5.2.14

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be quite easy using [`usort`](http://php.net/usort), which sorts the array using a user-defined comparison function.  The result might look something like this:

```
usort($posts, function($a, $b) use ($post_ids) {
    return array_search($a->ID, $post_ids) - array_search($b->ID, $post_ids);
});
```

Note that this solution, since it uses [anonymous functions and closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), requires PHP 5.3.

---

One easy solution for this pre-5.3 (the dark ages!) is to do this with a quick loop and then [`ksort`](http://php.net/ksort):

```
$ret = array();
$post_ids = array_flip($post_ids);
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $ret[$post_ids[$post->ID]] = $post;
}
ksort($ret);
```

Comment: I was typing this exact same solution, +1.
PS: i think you need to array_flip $post_ids before and after this function.

Comment: @Richard Tuin That would be one solution -- the other is to use `array_search`, as I was in the middle of correcting my post to use.

Comment: This looks like a very elegant solution, however, when I try and implement this, I'm getting confused to what the function is supposed to do?

If I copy it straight from here I get : 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION      ---- I feel like I should be creating a function to do the comparison? (excuse the misunderstanding as well... I'm no doubt having a retard moment)... edit: reading this http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php seems to make it a little clearer, but still stuck!

Comment: @Tisch `$posts` is your array of post objects; `$post_ids` is your array of ID values. To understand `usort`, it's probably easiest to read the manual page that I've linked to in my answer. If you are still uncertain, perhaps you could clarify what you're unsure about? This solution requires you have PHP 5.3 -- I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @lonesomeday looks like I have PHP Version 5.2.14... could explain a lot. Gutted, that looks like a nice and fast solution too.

Comment: @downvoter Why the downvote? This may not be a solution for the OP, but it isn't wrong...

Comment: @Tisch Have a look at my pre-5.3 solution.

Comment: You could use array_flip() instead of array_search for the pre 5.3 solution, which would be much better for sorting a large list

Comment: thanks guys! much faster solution. It's a media temple server by the way... you would think they would be up to date.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a nested looping mechanism to match up the order and ids and rebuild a new post array.

```
$new_post_array = array();

foreach($id_array as $id) {          //loop through custom ordered ids

    foreach($post_array as $post) {  //for every id loop through posts

        if($id == $post->ID){         //and when the custom ordered id matches the post->ID

            new_array[] = $post       //push the post on the new array

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Making a copy of both the arrays (that's what foreach does) is unneccesary here.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. This does the job, however seems a little sluggish? I've accepted the answer anyway because it does do what I am looking for, and works with PHP 5.2

Comment: sorry @jondavidjohn, I've had to switch to the faster solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sortOrderMap = array_flip($postIds);

usort($posts, function($postA, $postB) use ($sortOrderMap) {
    return $sortOrderMap[$postA->ID] - $sortOrderMap[$postB->ID];
});
```

You can simply subtract b from a instead of a from b to sort the other direction

Comment: thankyou for your answer as well... The solution above is very similar so I'm going to pursue that one if possible. Looks like PHP 5.2 is stopping me though :(